# RestKit and Swift bug response descriptors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapping, restkit

I have response descriptors added as result of function

```
class func responseDescriptors() -> [RKResponseDescriptor] {
        var successCodes : NSIndexSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful);

        var retResponseDescriptors : [RKResponseDescriptor] = [];

        //Settings
        retResponseDescriptors.append(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: BBLocalization.mapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: BBServerAPIPaths.Settings.LanguageTranslate.rawValue, keyPath: nil, statusCodes: successCodes));
        retResponseDescriptors.append(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: BBWakeUP.mapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "v1.2/user/wakeup", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: successCodes));

        //User
        retResponseDescriptors.append(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: BBUser.mapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "v1.2/user/:userId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: successCodes));

        return retResponseDescriptors;
    }
```

adding by call

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().addResponseDescriptorsFromArray(self.responseDescriptors());
```

mapping response localization work good, but if i call wakeUp it's mapping to

```
to object <BBUser: 0x7fbe306b1210>
```

if i not add response descriptor for user request

```
//User
//retResponseDescriptors.append(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: BBUser.mapping(), method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "v1.2/user/:userId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: successCodes));
```

works good, mapping into BBWake work.

In ObjectiveC this error not happen.

Why?

Mappings:

**BBWakeUP**

```
class func mapping() -> RKObjectMapping {
    var mapping : RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: BBWakeUP.self);
    mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["localization_hash" : "localizationHash"]);
    return mapping;
}
```

**BBUser**

```
class func userMapping() -> RKEntityMapping {
    var mapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "BBUser", inManagedObjectStore: RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore());
    mapping.identificationAttributes = ["userId"];
    mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id" : "userId"]);
    return mapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c you should see exactly the same behaviour because    `pathPattern: "v1.2/user/wakeup"` and `pathPattern: "v1.2/user/:userId"` are identical as far as the pattern matcher is concerned. So, whichever one is registered first will be used first.

If your obj-c is working then it is somehow differently specified.

Comment: Yes, in objective C same behaviour :(
And RestKit team think it's not a RestKit bug

Comment: It isn't a RestKit bug - it's physically impossible to tell the difference between two patterns with the same format